How to prevent Autocomplete from showing only the selected value after selection in React Hook Form?
I have an issue with an Autocomplete component that uses React Hook Form. When I select a value in the Autocomplete, the search input updates with the selected value, which results in the list of available options being narrowed down to only the selected item.
I am using two states: searchQuery for searching agents and selectedValue for storing the selected value. When I select an agent, selectedValue updates, but searchQuery also changes, resulting in only the selected agent being displayed in the list.
How can I separate these states so that the selected value does not affect the search input, and the list of options remains available for further searching?
Thanks in advance!
Here's my current component code:
  control,
  required,
  name = 'agent',
}: AutocompleteProps) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
  const [agents, setAgents] = useState<IAgents[]>([]);

  const agentsQuery = useGetAgentsQuery({ page, search: searchQuery });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (agentsQuery.isSuccess && agentsQuery.data?.results) {
      setAgents((prevAgents) =>
        page === 1
          ? agentsQuery.data.results
          : [...prevAgents, ...agentsQuery.data.results]
      );
    }
  }, [agentsQuery.data, page]);

  const handleInputChange = useDebouncedInputChange(setPage, setValue);

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={{ required: required }}
      defaultValue={required ? null : { label: '', id: '' }}
      render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
        <FormControl>
          <Autocomplete
            disabled={agentsQuery.isError}
            loading={agentsQuery.isFetching || agentsQuery.isLoading}
            freeSolo
            noOptionsText={'Ничего не найдено'}
            options={
              agents?.map((agent) => ({
                label: agent.name,
                id: agent.id,
              })) || []
            }
            ListboxProps={{
              onScroll: (event) =>
                handleScroll({
                  page,
                  event,
                  setPage,
                  dataQuery: agentsQuery,
                }),
            }}
            onInputChange={(_, val) => {
              handleInputChange(val);
            }}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label || ''}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              option?.id === value?.id && option?.label === value?.label
            }
            renderOption={(props, option) => {
              return (
                <span {...props} key={option?.id}>
                  {option?.label}
                </span>
              );
            }}
            {...field}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                value={params.inputProps.value || ''}
                placeholder={'Выберите агента'}
                label={'Выберите агента'}
                error={!!fieldState?.error}
              />
            )}
            inputValue={searchQuery}
            value={selectedValue}
            onChange={(_, value) => {
              field.onChange(value);
              setSelectedValue(value);
            }}
          />
          {fieldState?.error && (
            <FormHelperText error>{fieldState?.error.message}</FormHelperText>
          )}
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  );
};

  setPage: (page: number) => void,
  setValue: (value: string) => void,
  delay: number = 300
) => {
  return useCallback(
    _.debounce((inputValue: string) => {
      setPage(1);
      setValue(inputValue);
    }, delay),
    [setPage, setValue, delay]
  );
};

export default useDebouncedInputChange;

